# MacBook pro unresponsive / slow after startup

Tags: macbook-pro

After starting my macbook it is very slow/ not responding at all to mouse clicks and keystrokes. I do not get the famous beachball but just the normal pointer. On windows that are already open i can scroll content with the mousewheel or two fingers on the pad, but thats all the response. If i have a browser open it will respond to mouse over/hover but not to clicks.

I have not been able to find the cause for this, i have started up in safe boot, but after a while that gets the same problem, the disk shows to be ok and i started on single usermode to run fsck which also shows ok.

I have enough drive space and no processes / tasks eating away resources as far as i can see.

I run osx 10.6. On a macbook pro with 4gb ram, 500GB hdd, core i7

Any ideas or help would be very much welcome

Comment: For how long is it slow? What are the applications in your startup list? I think some application is holding you back on startup. Could be anything without knowing more.

Comment: It stays slow forever it seems, very long at least.  A few times I started up without it being slow and it became slow later on, in my list of startup programs is only the Microsoft Database Demon, so it can hardly be that.

Comment: Can you try two things and share the response with us?  If you're on wifi, turn wifi off and reboot.  Does the MBP response improve?  Can you run the hardware test to see if anything is acting up?  This would tell us if anything is failing.  Instructions on how to do it are in Apple's knowledge base article HT1509.  Thanks.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: I am now having the same issue with a late 2008 MacBook Pro running Lion (10.7.2).  I have 8GB RAM and no login items.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

- If your Mac is always slow, check the Activity Monitor.app for resource hogs. Alternatively you could enter `top -o cpu` in Terminal.app, and check the `%CPU` column.
- If your Mac is only slow at startup, check your login start items in System Preferences → Users & Groups → Login Items.